# Clearing bottom layer canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have 3 layers, one for the bg, one for the main canvas and one for the cursor.
It is a paint program, I want the cursor to be the brush and for this I redraw based on mouse move and clear the previous state with clear rect. When I click down with the mouse it will draw on the main canvas and you can pain this way. However when I run the program the clear rect seems to affect the bottom layers making them transparent?
Why does the background layer not stay white?

http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html

The listeners:

```
$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    paint = true;
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    redraw();


});

$('#canvas').mousemove(function (e) {
    if (paint) {
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
        redraw();
    }
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function (e) {
    paint = false;
});

$('#canvasCursor').mousemove(function (e) {

    ctxCursor.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    ctxCursor.beginPath();
    ctxCursor.arc(mouseX, mouseY, brushSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctxCursor.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxCursor.fill();

});

window.onload = function () {
    ctxBg.beginPath();
    ctxBg.rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctxBg.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctxBg.fill();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look and tracked down the problem. On line 19 of `Paint.js` you have this:

```
var ctxCursor = canvasBg.getContext('2d');
```

This should actually be:

```
var ctxCursor = canvasCursor.getContext('2d');
```

There were a few other issues so I cleaned them up and it's now working perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/VmvqJ/2/

This is your new `Paint.js` script:

```
//////////////////// Wayne Daly
///////////////////  03/06/2013

$(document).ready(function () {


    /////////////// SETTING UP CONTEXT & VARIABLES ///////////////
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        canvasWidth = canvas.width,
        canvasHeight = canvas.height;

    var canvasCursor = document.getElementById('canvasCursor'),
        ctxCursor = canvasCursor.getContext('2d');


    var mouseX,
        mouseY,
        clickX = [],
        clickY = [],
        clickDrag = [],
        paint = false,
        brushSize = 20;

    /////////////// EVENT HANDLERS ///////////////

    $('#canvasCursor').mousemove(function (e) {
        updateCursor(this, e);
        console.log(paint);
        if (paint) {
            addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
            redraw();
        }
    });

    $('#canvasCursor').mousedown(function (e) {
        console.log('down');
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        paint = true;
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        redraw();
    });

    $('#canvasCursor').mouseup(function (e) {
        console.log('up');
        paint = false;
    });


    /////////////// GENERAL FUNCTIONS ///////////////

    function updateCursor(elem, e) {
        ctxCursor.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        mouseX = e.pageX - elem.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - elem.offsetTop;

        ctxCursor.beginPath();
        ctxCursor.arc(mouseX, mouseY, brushSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctxCursor.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctxCursor.fill();
    }

    function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
        clickX.push(x);
        clickY.push(y);
        clickDrag.push(dragging);
    }


    function Paint(e) {

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, brushSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fill();

    }

    function redraw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

        ctx.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;

        for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
                ctx.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
            } else {
                ctx.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
            }
            ctx.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

});
```

and add this in between your page's `<head>` tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background:#303030;
}
#canvas, #canvasCursor {
    cursor: none;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#canvasCursor {
    z-index: 20;
    background: none;
}
</style>
```

Then replace your `<body>` tag and everything inside it with this:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvasCursor" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: But how can I make it so it just clears the top layer and lets the bottom ones show? I want the cursor layer to show the circle like its doing now but when you click then it draws on the canvas layer?

Comment: @StevenBarrett - I'm just working on a solution, I'll post it in a few minutes :)

Comment: @StevenBarrett - I've just updated my answer. I had to make quite a few changes but it now works! Basically, the events are now attached to `#canvasCursor` but the drawing is done on `#canvas`.

Comment: http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html thank you, I can now make go adding features! :) ps was the issue the background being non-tansparent?

Comment: @StevenBarrett - no problem! The main issue was that the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events were attached to `#canvas` but `#canvas` was underneath the transparent `#canvasCursor` so none of the events were ever triggered.